# I can not get the full path of a file uploaded in nodejs

Tags: node.js, file, path

I am testing it with postman the image is uploaded to the backend but I can not get the file name

this is the error

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')
at uploadAvatar (/var/www/html/room/room-backend/controllers/room.js:741:33)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/room/room-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/var/www/html/room/room-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Form. (/var/www/html/room/room-backend/node_modules/connect-multiparty/index.js:114:7)
at Form.emit (node:events:527:28)
at emitCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:145:10)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

this the line      `var files = req.files.file.path;`

this console.log is empty     `console.log(files);`

room.routes

```
var express = require('express');

var RoomController = require('../controllers/room');

var router = express.Router();
var md_auth = require('../middlewares/authenticated');

var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var md_upload = multipart({ uploadDir: './uploads/rooms' });



// Rutas de usuarios
router.post('/save', RoomController.save);
router.put('/update', md_auth.authenticated, RoomController.update);
router.put('/updateimage1', RoomController.updateImage1);
router.post('/saveimg', RoomController.saveImg);
//router.post('/saveimg/:id/:image1/', RoomController.saveImg);
router.post('/upload-avatar',  md_upload, RoomController.uploadAvatar);
```

room.controller

```
var fs = require('fs');
//import * as fs from 'node:fs';
var path = require('path');

//const path = require('node:path');

var User = require('../models/user');
var jwt = require('../services/jwt');
var Room = require('../models/room');



uploadAvatar: function(req, res) {
 
     var files = req.files.file.path;
     console.log(files);
```

I dont know where is the error.

I am using nodejs 17.8.0

Comment: As far as I can see in the code of  `connect-multiparty` the key for `req.files` would be the file's original name before being uploaded and not the field's name in your form (or form-data).
Can you try using `console.log(Object.keys(req.files));` to verify if that's the case?

Comment: I did it I got []
ReferenceError: files is not defined
    at uploadAvatar (/var/www/html/room/room-backend/controllers/room.js:743:18)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/room/room-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)

Comment: From what I can understand either you're not sending the file correctly or there's a bug somewhere in another part of your code. Are you willing to try `express-fileupload` (very similar usage) or `multer` and send the file from an HTML page instead of `postman`?

Comment: I tried with express-fileupload doesnt work and I have a front end with angular as well doesnt works because the backend doesnt get the file object

Comment: I think the problem is bodyparser I had commented the line but as well I have bodyparser deprecated

Answer (score 0):

In your code `uploadAvatar` method
changed the `req.files.file.path` to `req.file.path`
it should work now